# product of K-theory vs product of reduced K-theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory

In Hatcher's [book](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) pp.54 there is an isomorphism between product of K-theory and that of reduced K-theory

$$K(X) \otimes K(Y) \cong \left(\widetilde{K}(X) \otimes \widetilde{K}(Y)\right) \oplus \widetilde{K}(X) \oplus \widetilde{K}(Y) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$$

Could somebody explain what this isomorphism is?

Comment: This follows from $K(X) \cong \tilde K(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @MikeMiller: do you mean the following? $$K(X) \otimes K(Y) \cong \left(\widetilde{K}(X) \oplus \mathbb{Z}\right) \otimes \left(\widetilde{K}(Y) \oplus \mathbb{Z}\right) = \left(\widetilde{K}(X) \otimes \widetilde{K}(Y)\right) \oplus \left(\widetilde{K}(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}\right) \oplus \left(\mathbb{Z} \otimes \widetilde{K}(Y)\right) \oplus \left(\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}\right) \cong \left(\widetilde{K}(X) \otimes \widetilde{K}(Y)\right) \oplus \widetilde{K}(X) \oplus \widetilde{K}(Y) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Other than the processing error it compiles to on my end, I do.

Comment: @MikeMiller: sorry Mike, what processing error do you refer to?

Comment: The TeX you posted doesn't compile correctly for me. Could just be an error on my computer. Don't worry about it.